# Dyadic Predicate Formalisation of Sentences

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

Using predicates $Px$ for "x is a person" and $Rx,y$ for "x is the father of y" and secondly taking reference to people as implicit and using only the two-place predicate Rx,y.

> 1. No one has no father.
> 2. No one has fathered no one.
> 3. Some people are the fathers of someone’s father.
> 4. Anyone who has fathered someone’s father has fathered someone.

---

My ideas:

1. $\neg\exists x(Px \land \forall y(Py\rightarrow\neg Ry,x) \equiv  \neg\exists x\forall y(\neg Ry,x)$

   ---
2. $\neg\exists x(Px \land \forall y(Py\land\neg Rx,y) \equiv  \neg\exists x\forall y(\neg Rx,y)$

   ---
3. $\exists x(\exists y(Ry,x) \land \exists z(Rx,z))$

   ---
4. $\forall y\exists z\exists x(Ry,z \land Rz,x \land Ry,x)$

---

Any help would be kindly appreciated, I'm not too sure what the solutions are to these formalisations. They are quite tricky! Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: I disagree on 2. "No one has fathered no one" means "Everyone has fathered (i.e. has a son/daughter)" : $∀x∃y(Rx,y)$.

Comment: For 3. I suggest : $∃x∃y∃z[(Rx,y) ∧ (Ry,z)]$.

Comment: So I think we agree on 1. and 2. now. I've changed my question above to my new suggestions for 3. and 4.! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $\forall x (Px \rightarrow \exists y (Py \land Ry,x))$ or $\neg \exists x (Px \land \forall y (Py \land \neg Ry,x))$ (without $Px$: $\forall x \exists y Ry,x$ or $\neg \exists x \forall y \neg Ry,x$)
2. $\neg \exists x (Px \land \forall y (Py \rightarrow \neg Rx,y))$ or $\forall x (Px \rightarrow \exists y (Py \land Rx,y))$ (without $Px$: $\neg \exists x \forall y \neg Rx,y$ or $\forall x \exists y Rx,y$)
3. $\exists x \exists y \exists z (Rx,y \land Ry,z)$
4. $\forall x (\exists y \exists z (Rx,y \land Ry,z) \rightarrow \exists w Rx,w)$

Answer (score 1):

1. is fine, though you could also do $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow \exists y ( P(y) \land R(y,x)))$ and $\forall x \exists y R(y,x)$ (everyone has a father)
2. is like 1, but with the role of $x$ and $y$ reversed. So: $\neg \exists x (P(x) \land \forall y (P(y) \rightarrow \neg R(x,y)))$ and $\neg \exists x \forall y \neg R(x,y)$.  Alternatively: $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow \exists y (P(y) \land R(x,y)))$ and (as Mauro suggests) $\forall x \exists y R(x,y)$
3. Why do you have a negation in here?!  Try again.
4. Same here: why the negation?! Also, you will need four quantifiers: one for the first 'anyone', one for the persn they fathered (who itself is the father of someone, so that's a third), and a final one for the last 'someone'. Again, try this one again.

Comment: Thanks again @Bram28 ! Have realised that I'm going to need 3 quantifiers for no. 3 and 4 for no.4. Will try again and edit my inserts soon.

Comment: So I've got $\neg\exists x(Px \land \forall y(Py\land\neg Rx,y) \equiv  \neg\exists x\forall y(\neg Rx,y)$  which is the same as what you suggest for no. 2! Will work on 3 and 4 later. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, so I realised that I typed out my answers for no. 3 and no. 4 incorrectly, hence why the random $\neg$ appears!

Comment: 3. $\exists x(Px \land \forall y(Py \rightarrow\exists z (Rz,y,x)))$

Comment: @Andy That universal isn't right: it says *some* people are the father of *some* one's father ... so you need a bunch of existentials there! Also, $Rz,y,x$ isn't right since $R$ only takes 2 arguments. In English, what are you trying to say about $x$, $y$, and $z$?

Comment: 3. $\exists x(\exists y(Ry,x) \land \exists z(Rx,z))$ Would this be better? So someone y fathered someone x and someone x fathered someone z?

Comment: 4. Looks a little like this perhaps: [Son - 'Someone'] $\rightarrow$ [Dad] $\rightarrow$ [Grandad - 'Anyone']? So I think this should look like: $\forall y\exists z\exists x(Ry,z \land Rz,x \land Ry,x)$ Which basically means: For all Grandads that fathered a Dad, the Dad fathered a Son and so the Grandad fathered the Son.